# PHP tiles using URL variables

Tags: php

I would like to create dynamic titles using PHP. My URLs look like this:

domain.com/results?cityid=3432&type=1

I would like to be able to define cityid=3432 as "New York City" and type=1 as "Condos" etc. so that meaningful title tags are created using URL variables that I define.

i.e. domain.com/results?cityid=3432&type=1 would produce a title tag reading "New York City Condos"

There will be hundreds of different variables to define, so it might be best to use an external file.

I saw another solution on this site, but it was flagged as being vulnerable to attack.

Comment: You have a typo in your title

Answer (score 0):

If you have the city ids with their corresponding city names (same goes for types) stored in a database it is pretty simple:

1. You will extract the id from the url with get and query against your
   cities-table fetching the city name and saving it in variable.
2. You do that for the type.
3. You combine both as you like and use it as title tag value.

If you are not using databases, you will need to store all combinations in arrays inside a file and include them. Afterwards you will achieve your title tag value:

```
<?php

//Save this into a seperate file e.g. titlecodes.php
//Modify those arrays until they meet your requirements
$cities = array(1=> "Washington", 2 => "Los Angeles");
$types = array(1 => "House", 2 => "Penthouse", 3=> "Industrial");

// Include titlecodes.php in your script 
$type = '';
$city = '';
if(isset($_GET["city_id"]) && array_key_exists($_GET["city_id"], $cities)) 
    $city = $cities[$_GET["city_id"]];
if(isset($_GET["type"]) && array_key_exists($_GET["type"], $types)) 
    $type = $types[$_GET["type"]];

$titleTagValue = $city . " " . $type;

//put it in header title 
//<header>
//<title><php echo $titleTagValue </title>
//</header>
```

Comment: should add 404 when not defined ;p

Comment: Sure, you're correct. Or a message like "heeelppp , i don't exit" :)

Comment: I am not using a database. However, I can create a text file with two columns. Column A will contain the variable found in the URL and column B will contain the English equivalent that I want printed in the title. The URL strings can be very long and contain many different variables. I would like to define all of them in a text file and have the PHP look for any matches. There could potentially be hundreds of thousands of potential combinations. i.e. cityid=3432&type=1&minbed=2&maxprice=500000. I would want "New York City Condos 2 Bedrooms $500,000" printed into the title tag.